# iptables rule active only for certain port

Tags: iptables

I have the following rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 93.xxx.61.56 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.10
```

Problem is that this rule affects some programs and I want this rule to be active only for a specific port like 443.

Is it possible to do that? I mean, everything else that tries to connect to 93.xxx.61.56 on a different port than 443 should not be affected by this rule.

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 93.xxx.61.56 --sport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.10d
```

Comment: Damn. The answer above got it before me.

Comment: Weird that --sport instead of --dport fixed it. That too without -m tcp.

Answer (score 3):

Add `-p tcp --dport 443` to your command, and then it will only match TCP packets with destination port = 443.